# Ruby on Rails Passenger installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, passenger

user@ubuntu: ~/Documents/WorkSpace/proj1$ rvmsudo bundle exec rake passenger config_dev[proj1]

[sudo] password for user:

rake aborted!

RVM- Ruby integration was done to a separate gem, it should be installed by default with RVM, remove the 'LOAD_PATH.unshift' and all should be fine again.

I am new to rails please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

follow instructions here: https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/